# Firewall rules for process

Tags: firewall

Is there a way to create (outgoing) firewall rules that apply to a specific process only? I'm currently running various *buntus. All 16.04 or 16.10.

On Windows, nearly all firewalls have the ability to create rules that apply to specific processes, in addition to the regular network rules.

Can this be achieved on Ubuntu distros?

Comment: http://www.tecmint.com/open-source-security-firewalls-for-linux-systems/

Comment: @kashish I don't see on that page whay I'm looking for. I know about firewalls for Linux and Linux based firewalls. Which of those can create rules for a process? I'm NOT asking about network rules (i.e. source/destination addres, ports, protocols etc). The article doesn't denote this feature about any of them.